# wx.adv.CalendarCtrl in wxPython does not work with sizers

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I would need add calendar to my small utility. I have a hello world code like this:

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import wx.adv as adv

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='My fancy form app with calendar')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        my_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(400,450))

        # Headline Text
        self.headline_text = wx.StaticText(panel, style = wx.TE_CENTER & ~wx.TE_LEFT & ~wx.TE_RIGHT, label="This text will be placed to the top of my form")
        my_sizer.Add(self.headline_text, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Calendar under the text
        self.cal = adv.CalendarCtrl(self, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        my_sizer.Add(self.cal, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Without the block of code with Calendar, this works well. BoxSizer can arrange buttons, text labels, tables etc. - But the calendar kills the sizer and everything is in the top left corner.

So please, what is the proper usage of CalendarCtrl object? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You were placing the calendar on the frame

```
self.cal = adv.CalendarCtrl(self ...
```

and the text on the panel

```
self.headline_text = wx.StaticText(panel ...
```

- all widgets should really go on panels.

I have also moved all of your widgets to a panel class which helps with separation of concerns

```
import wx
import wx.stc as stc
import wx.adv as adv

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='My fancy form app with calendar')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.SetMinSize(wx.Size(400,450))
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """Create a panel class to contain screen widgets."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        # Headline Text
        self.headline_text = wx.StaticText(self, style = wx.TE_CENTER & ~wx.TE_LEFT & ~wx.TE_RIGHT, label="This text will be placed to the top of my form")
        sizer.Add(self.headline_text, 0, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)

        # Calendar under the text
        self.cal = adv.CalendarCtrl(self, 10, wx.DateTime.Now())
        sizer.Add(self.cal, 0, wx.ALL | wx.CENTER, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't understand how I missed it

Comment: Ha. Ha. I've learned the hard way :)